# AvaloniaUI - how to change the 'style' of the window (borderless, toolbox, etc)

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia, window-style

I'm trying out Avalonia UI and I need a ToolWindow. I tried different approaches but the wpf equivalent WindowStyle seems not supported. The only thing I was able to do was to use 'CanResize', but even that allows resizing via the max button ...
... 'CanResize' implies that at least no max button should be present, but I can imagine that reasons are in place to argue if the min button should be hidden as well in this scenario.

Am I overlooking something or is this not implemented yet ?

My next thing on the todo-list is a Splash screen (borderless), this falls under the same umbrella. Possible yet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A borderless window is easily possible in v. 0.10, by setting these properties on the window:

```
ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1"
```

For a tool Window you could use a borderless and frameless window and then implement the buttons yourself. You can look for inspiration over [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/4540).

Comment: super frankenapps ! Will give that a go later today ! Any idea when 0.10 will be out of preview ? 

Any idea btw on when v1.0 will arrive ? Know in 2020 'next year' was mentioned, but rather beginning of this year or end of 2021 ?

Comment: That solved it indeed. It is now a RC and no longer a preview (although it still is a preview package), so V.0.10 comes closer !

The 'CanResize' also works correct and disables the maximize button.

Comment: Well I am quite sure it’s going to be in the beginning of this year... Also I already use it for all my projects and it’s already really stable...

Comment: Good news, finally a cross-platform desktop UI for C#. Is it production stable ? I need UI for win, mac and linux and currently I'm using javafx and java as the front-end and .net core c# as the backend (all locally). It would be nice to have it all in .Net Core. I know I could do it all in java, but core is faster and more optimized at this moment and I need performance ... I expect to go public/beta in Q3-Q4 of this year. The UI is not extremely heavy, but I need custom drawing on canvas, but I will ask that in another question. Should I go for Avalonia or JavaFX in your opinion ?

Comment: Well, thats definitely not related to the question, but in my opinion I would go with Avalonia. They also provide access to the SkiaSharp Canvas, so that seems fitting to me.

Comment: OK, Thanks frankenapps ! I will dive deeper into Avalonia and SkiaSharp (canvas). I know it is off-topic, but sometimes one must go for it while the wright moment/person is there ! I will ask my further questions in new topics.